# Take screenshot with PhantomJS from PHP and pass arguments to the script

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I need to pass variable but not working

php

```
exec('phantomjs screenshot.js http://www.google.com google.png');
```

js

```
var args = require('system').args;
var page = require('webpage').create();
var address = system.args[1];
var image = system.args[2];

page.open(address , function () {
    page.render(image);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

if i run script without php i have

```
    phantomjs screenshot.js http://google.com google.com
0: screenshot.js
1: http://google.com
2: google.com
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: system
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phantomjs can't find `system` variable because it is not defined.

You need to write either

```
var args = require('system').args;
var address = args[1];
var image = args[2];
```

or you could write

```
var system = require('system');
var address = system.args[1];
var image = system.args[2];
```